# Having trouble booting up my system

Tags: boot, 20.04, boot-repair

I was using my computer which runs on 20.04 Ubuntu. I turned off my computer and then immediately turned it on, which presented me face to face with this screen:

[image: screenshot]

I am now lost and have no clue of what to do next. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your release; as you've mentioned 20.04 in the description but have tagged you're using Ubuntu 14.04?  Please clarify (*or correct if tag was in error*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Are you install ubuntu 20.04 then reboot?
if it's the scenario, you probably miss some packages on installation time. So try  `ctrl + Alt + F1` on boot freeze time to open terminal.

update and upgrade you system :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and update grub:

`sudo update-grub`